# Welcom Bot для группы Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Бот должен приветствовать участника который только присоединился к группе после чего удалить свое сообщение через 15 мин. 
Каким методом и как это оформить используя библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI?

Answer (score 1):

Ну бот сперва должен понять что кто-то зашел в группу, и поняв это отправить сообщение `f'@{username} приветствую тебя!'`.

Затем создать добавить в список приветствий данное приветствие, и асинхронно проверять каждую минуту весь список сообщений с приветствиями прошло ли 15 минут с момента отправки и если да то удалять данное сообщение, а удаление можно сделать с помощью метода `delete_message`.

Нашел данный метод в исходниках самого бота [ссылка](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/151880f3919e51692008e635781ef758560f3379/telebot/__init__.py#L614), но в документации она не была указана..

```
def delete_message(self, chat_id, message_id):
    """
    Use this method to delete message. Returns True on success.
    :param chat_id: in which chat to delete
    :param message_id: which message to delete
    :return: API reply.
    """
    return apihelper.delete_message(self.token, chat_id, message_id)
```

Как видишь по написанному комментарию, нужно боту указать `id` чата ну и `id` сообщения следовательно..